# How to show a progress bar inside a layout?

Tags: android, progress-bar

i am using a custom notification layout. Notification layout is inside an activity. Notification layout does not fill the entire portion of the screen. It takes only 1/4 of the screen. I want to show the progress bar inside the notification layout.so my question is

> 1. How to set the position of progress bar(other than using

(ProgressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);)

> 1. Can we set the width and height of progress bar( atleast to the size of the layout)

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: ProgressBar is considered a view, so you can add it like any other view (either in your XML or programmically).  Check Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to set the position of progress bar": use it like any other types of View (xml will be simpler).

"Can we set the width and height of progress bar( at least to the size of the layout)":

android:maxHeight       An optional argument to supply a maximum height for thisview. 
android:maxWidth        An optional argument to supply a maximum width for this view. 
android:minHeight